# Why does my code not work? It passed 8 out of 600 cases on GFG. The Question is "leaf at same level"

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree

My Approach is this- I used an arraylist. I checked all the nodes of the Binary Tree, to find those whose left and right node are null, which signifies that they are a leaf, then I found out their levels and added them to an arraylist.

After this I used the Arraylist in the function boolean check to check whether all the elements of the array list are same of not, if they are i return true (all leaves are at the same level) otherwise I return false.

```
class Solution {
    boolean check(Node root) {
        int c = 0;
        ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int x : a) {
            if (x != (a.get(0)))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void che(Node root, int level, ArrayList<Integer> a) {
        if (root == null) return;
        if (root.left == null && root.right == null) {
            a.add(level);
        }
        che(root.right, level + 1, a);
        che(root.left, level + 1, a);
    }
}
```

[This is the link for the Question](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/leaf-at-same-level/1#)

Comment: `check` ***always*** returns `true`, you completely ignore `root` / the entire tree.

Comment: No need to collect all the leaves first. Just do a depth-first search to visit all the leaves one by one, store the level of the last leaf and compare it to the level of the current leaf. If they are different you're done. If they aren't, continue until you find a difference or hit the end in which case you'd return true.

Comment: You are missing a `che(root, 0, a);` call.

Comment: @Thomas's solution is better, don't need last loop to check different level.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The `che` function is never called.

It is however not necessary to collect data in an array list. Instead make the recursive function return the *height* of the subtree it is called on. In the same function compare the height that is returned for the left and right subtree. If they are different, return a special value to indicate failure (like -2), otherwise return that common height plus one.

This allows the function to abort the search as soon as a height difference is found, avoiding the unnecessary traversal of the rest of the tree.

Here is how that would look:

```
class Solution
{
    boolean check(Node root) {
        return height(root) > -2;
    }

    private int height(Node root) {
        if (root == null) return -1;
        int left = height(root.left);
        if (left == -2) return -2;
        int right = height(root.right);
        if (left == -1 || right == -1 || left == right) {
            return 1 + Math.max(left, right);
        }
        return -2;
    }
}
```